# How Can Set CBR (constant Bit Rate) in Call Recorder?

Tags: android, recorder

I use This code Record Calls But Bit Rate Its Variable (VBR) Now I want change To constant (CBR).

```
myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioChannels(2);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(48000);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(128000);
```

How Can Change To CBR?

Answer (score 0):

AMR means Adaptive Multi Rate which basically means it's variable.
You have to use another encoder.

Comment: Try different encoder: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html